# ember data computed property not working on nested association

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a simple datamodel:

a Leg, has many Players, who have many Turns:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Leg = DS.Model.extend({
  players: DS.hasMany('App.Player'),
  turnCount: function() {
    var i = 0;
    this.get('players').forEach(function(p) {
      i+= p.get('turns.length');
    });
    return i;
  }.property('players.@each.turns.length')

});

App.Player = DS.Model.extend({
  leg: DS.belongsTo('App.Leg'),
  turns: DS.hasMany('App.Turn')
});


App.Turn = DS.Model.extend({
  player: DS.belongsTo('App.Player')
});
```

The computed property `turnCount` doesn't automatically get updated when I create a new Turn, but it should, right?

```
/*
* do this on the console to verify
*/

var leg = App.Leg.createRecord();
var player = leg.get('players').createRecord();

leg.get('turnCount');
// => 0
player.get('turns').createRecord();
leg.get('turnCount')
// => 0
```

**UPDATE**

It seems that if you stick to one layer of nesting things just work. So:

```
.property('players.@each.someProperty')
```

works, as long as that someProperty is not an Enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.property('players.@each.turns.@each')
```

You could also use the [`reduce`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_reduce) method to calculate totals:

```
turnCount: function() {
  return this.get('players').reduce(function(value, player) {
    return value + player.get('turns.length');
  }, 0);
}.property('players.@each.turns.@each')
```