# Ember.js: Controller property not called when attribute changed

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a dynamic controller property which returns booleans if a relationship count is below 5:

```
alienCountBelow5: function() {
  return this.get('model').get('aliens').content.length < 5;
}.property('aliens'),
```

But even as I have specified that it should monitor `aliens` for changes, it doesn't change when I add a new record to the relationship.

This is the model:

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  aliens: DS.hasMany('alien')
});
```

I use `pushObject` on the `aliens` object when I have created a new record.

I am unsure how this should be done, apparently I am not doing it correctly.

Demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yegiku/2/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [the docs for `@each`](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/) - it's a special keyword that observes specific changes to an array.

In your case, using the following would work (the observer fires only when records are *added* or *removed* from the array):

```
alienCountBelow5: function() {
  return this.get('model').get('aliens.length') < 5;
}.property('aliens.[]'),
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. After updating `alienCountBelow5` per your suggestion, I got an error "Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined". Then I tried adding `{async:true}` to the relationship but then I was at status quo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yegiku/2/edit

Comment: Okay, now that I see your code I understand. The reason it's not working is because your `model` is an *array* of records, so putting a computed property on your `ArrayController` won't be useful. Instead, I put the property on your model (you could also put it on an `ItemController` if you don't think that's model-related logic). See here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/poqobevukozo/1/edit

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. Thanks for the example with `ArrayController` and `ItemController`!

Answer (score 1):

`alienCountBelow5` computed property should be defined inside `App.Item`. and change your template to `{{item.alienCountBelow5}}`. I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/repuq/1/edit).

Note: Unfortunately I couldn't get it working, It throws an error: `Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined`. It should work as it's the same as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860352/ember-data-computed-property-not-working-on-nested-association). But you should get the idea, and fix the issue. Also if you use

`aliens: DS.hasMany('alien', {async: true})` it kind of works.

Comment: Aha, so the difference-maker is to do it on the model: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yegiku/2/edit

Comment: But I thought controllers were for decorating models, so what's the deal here? This is in my optic decoration of a model.

Comment: Ye but `alienCountBelow5` is a property for a single item model, your controller is an `ArrayController`, that is, it is for all the item models. If you had a controller for Item, that is optimal, and you can have the decorator then.

Comment: @RonniEgeriis I didn't get your jsbin, did you edit it, did you manage to get it working?